# How do I find the magnetic field using an amperian loop in this problem? Is it even necessary?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

[image]

For part a, I need to use $\vec{F}=\nabla (\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B})$. So I need to find $\vec{B}$. I see that the current points up, so the magnetic field will curl around the slab in the $\hat \phi$ direction. Inside the center, I think the magnetic field is zero. On the sides where $x=\pm a$, I think the magnetic field curls. I know that at some point I need to use an amperian loop, but I'm not sure why or how.

Comment: Finding the magnetic field is problem 5.14 in my edition of Griffiths (3rd). Try looking at the techniques in that chapter. Example 5.8 almost looks similar, except that it's a sheet.

Comment: Ok I did that and found the magnetic field to be $-\mu_0 x J_0 \hat y$ for $x<-a$ and $\mu_0 x J_0 \hat y$ for $x>a$. I think the magnetic field inside the slab is zero, but the answer says it should be $\mu_0 x J_0 \hat y$. Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: $x = 0$ is the center of the slab. But to apply the del operator, you need an expression for force, not just the force at a position.